# Access entire urls for a particular keyword

Tags: c#

My project need to compare output(only urls) of google and yahoo for a particular keyword.

Can i access entire urls for a particular keyword from google and yahoo? Do they provide any library or any other thing for that?how can i do that?..

Comment: What URLs are you looking for/at? Perform a search, and then scan the results page for URLs containing the word?

Comment: means links which is given for each results.I should not scan entire results page for that.without using that any library or API for google and yahoo?if so how can i access??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you are looking for, but the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28VS.80%29.aspx) class will allow you get the HTML for a URL.

You can process the HTML with the [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack).

This will give you a list of all links in the document:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("file.htm");
IEnumerable<HtmlNode> links = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");
```

Comment: means for a particular result, google(also yahoo) will display maximum 100 pages of results.Without reading each pages line by line any other way to retrieve all urls(links)?

Comment: The HTML agility pack will let you query the HTML with XPath, so you could retrieve all URLs on each page in one go.

Comment: can you please give an example for that??

Comment: @Nikhil K - Example given. This is adapted from an example from the Agility pack site.

Comment: Same thing for each page. If you can get one page, I am sure you can figure out 100.

Comment: 1) sir,i think i have to use 'for' loop for that.Right?
 eg:
          for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i=i+10) //for reading 100 pages
            {
              doc.Load("http://www.google.com/search?   hl=en&q=c#&start=" + i + "");
 // code for reading
}

2) Also there is an error(assembly reference) for HtmlDocument,HtmlNode.I am not included extra namespaces or classes.
What ever there are default of VS2008 for asp.net.So any thing extra i need to add?

So i could not check for all code.

Comment: sir ,now i can read entire urls from 100 pages of google and yahoo for a particular keyword using 'for' loop. code is --->
 for (int i = 1; i < 100; i = i + 10)
            {
                string searchHtml1 = wc.DownloadString("http://in.search.yahoo.com/search?p=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(TextBox1.Text) + "pstart=1&b="+i+"");
 doc1.LoadHtml(searchHtml1);
 foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode link1 in doc1.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
 { HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlAttribute att1 = link1.Attributes["href"];
 zz1 += att1.Value; }}
But it is taking more time.Any way to reduce the time??

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for something like a web service provided by Google, Yahoo, <put your favorite search engine here> that you can send a "query" and get back just the links it would return if you entered the term in the search-box? So you don't have to parse the HTML that would normally be sent back to the browser but get the links and only the links.

If this is what you are looking for you might have a look at the [Google SOAP Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/soapsearch/reference.html), or better at it's successor the [Google AJAX Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/).

I have never used something like this but it seems this could help you.

Comment: But google api will give only 10 result for a request,right??
Is it possible to access entire urls which is given on google's normal output??

Comment: @Nikhil K - Just to make sure: so you do want to do what my post describes (did I understand your question correctly)? By *access entire urls* you mean **all** URLs <whatever search machine> would return if you used it on the web? I will not be able to help you a lot with the Google API as I did never use it. But maybe someone else does? And hopefully I could help clarify to others what you want to achieve.

Comment: Yes,you understood that.I read about google api from google.It is telling that you can access maximum 10 result for a query at a time.